# VBA; 1 column with multiple criteria, second column single criteria

Tags: vba

This is an update from a previous question I had. 
This time around, I am adding one more condition in a specific column. 
So this code replaces the cell/s based on multiple criteria on 2 separate columns. 
What my code is doing is it will look for ABC or DEF on Col B and if it shows XXX on Col F, it will replace it with YYY. I wrote the code below but it does nothing on the second criteria (DEF)

Appreciate your suggestions in advance!

```
Dim destlist As Worksheet, y As Long

fndList = Array("XXX")
rplcList = Array("YYY")

For Each sht In ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets
sht.Cells.AutoFilter Field:=2, Criteria1:="ABC"
sht.Cells.AutoFilter Field:=2, Criteria2:="DEF"     

'Loop through each item in Array lists and replace
For y = LBound(fndList) To UBound(fndList)
  sht.UsedRange.Columns("F").Replace What:=fndList(y), Replacement:=rplcList(y), _
        LookAt:=xlPart, SearchOrder:=xlByRows, MatchCase:=False, _
        SearchFormat:=False, ReplaceFormat:=False
Next y
sht.AutoFilterMode = False
```

Next sht

Comment: You know that the replace will do all the cells in column F, not just the visible ones due to the filter?

Comment: Hi Scott, nope I didnt know that. when I run my code, it does the job in replacing the cells in Col f with YYY when it says ABC in Col B and XXX in Col F. But it does not when it shows DEF in Col B and XXX in Col F.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're not entering correctly an "either or" criteria, and as @ScottCraner said, you were not limiting the replacement to the visible cells.

Try it this way:

```
sht.UsedRange.AutoFilter Field:=2, Criteria1:="ABC", Operator:=xlOr, Criteria2:="DEF"
sht.UsedRange.Columns("F").SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible).Replace ...
```

p.s. ok I note that `Replace` automatically works on the visible cells, but it is better to be *explicit* in the code.

Comment: @jackie yes, a few replacement are suggested, the rest of the code stays as is.